# How can i implement "doc" function in clisp?

Tags: clojure, clisp

In clojure, i can use doc as below:

```
Clojure> (doc juxt)
-------------------------
clojure.core/juxt
```

([f] [f g] [f g h] [f g h & fs])
    Alpha - name subject to change.
    Takes a set of functions and returns a fn that is the juxtaposition
    of those fns. The returned fn takes a variable number of args, and
    returns a vector containing the result of applying each fn to the
    args (left-to-right).
    ((juxt a b c) x) => [(a x) (b x) (c x)]enter code here

It seems there is no such a function in clisp ?  Then how can i implement such a function ?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`describe` works:

```
(describe #'expt)
#<SYSTEM-FUNCTION EXPT> is a built-in system function.
Argument list: (#:ARG0 #:ARG1)
For more information, evaluate (DISASSEMBLE #'EXPT).nter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

Lisp has Documentation Strings.

For example:

```
[1]> (defun sqr (x)
       "Returns the square of x"
       (* x x))
SQR
[2]> (documentation 'sqr 'function)
"Returns the square of x"
[3]>
```

Refer to the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_docume.htm#documentation) or this less detailed [explanation](http://www.psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter10.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks! But it seems many functions has no document string in clisp   (documentation 'expt 'function)
NIL